# Scrapy loop over spider

Tags: python, loops, scrapy, web-crawler

I'd like to loop over my `scrapy.Spider` somehow like this

```
for i in range(0, 10): 

   class MySpider(scrapy.Spider, ABC):

        start_urls = ["example.com"]
    
        def start_requests(self):
            for url in self.urls:
                if dec == i:
                    yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse_data, args={"wait": 1.5})
    
        def parse_data(self, response):
            data= response.css("td.right.data").extract()
            items["Data"] = data
            yield items
    
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings["FEED_URI"] = f"/../Data/data_{i}.json"
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
        process.crawl(MySpider)
        process.start()
```

However, this yields

```
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

Using

```
process.start(stop_after_crawl=False)
```

executes the script for `i=0` but than hangs at `i=1`

Comment: I need to ask - why?

Answer (score 1):

You can use multi-processing, or [LoopingCall](https://docs.twisted.org/en/stable/api/twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall.html).

You can read about `scheduling tasks for the future` [in twisted reactor documentation](https://docs.twisted.org/en/stable/core/howto/time.html#scheduling-tasks-for-the-future).

```py
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner


# callback for when the loop is finished
def cbLoopDone(result):
    reactor.stop()


_loopCounter = 0
loopTimes = 3
configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})


def run_spider():
    global _loopCounter
    # add whatever you want to check before running another spider
    if _loopCounter >= loopTimes:
        loop.stop()
        return

    _loopCounter += 1
    runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())
    runner.crawl('exampleSpider')


loop = task.LoopingCall(run_spider)

# Start looping every 5 seconds
loopDeferred = loop.start(5.0)

# Add callbacks for stop
loopDeferred.addCallback(cbLoopDone)

reactor.run()
```